# Captain America Civil War 7-3 = 5

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America : Civil War*, in the first present day scene, the one with Rumlow when the fight breaks out, Captain America says:

> I make 7 hostiles.

Then Falcon flies in and takes down 3, leaving 4 but he says:

> I make 5

I noticed it the first time I watched it, but this time around, I made sure I didn't miss anything.

So what is going on?

Comment: One was hiding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Then falcon flies in and takes down 3

Actually, he lands on 2 and kicks them down...but my interpretation is that one of them **got back up**. There's no indication there were 3 separate bad guys...although the action is fast-paced.

So, there were only TWO in the first place.

[image]

In any case, Cap was wrong...there were at least ELEVEN hostiles (including Rumlow).

[image]

Comment: and we had benefit of video playback. Shows how easy it is done in the heat of battle.

Comment: I thought that Cap had already subtracted the ones he put down.